# How long does an open bottle of Sake last?

Tags: storage, temperature, sake

I received a very large bottle of Sake, but have not opened it because I am sure I can't drink it all quickly.  Once I open it how long can I expect it to last, and what's the best way to keep it good for the longest possible.

What temperature should it be stored at, and what's the best temperate when drinking it?

Comment: I've never had a bottle last more than an hour.

Comment: A full double magnum takes a while to consume unless you have a large group - that's why I am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into small aluminum containers and store it in the fridge. Fill it to the top so there is very little air in the container.  You can find kid sized 12 oz water bottles on sell for just a few bucks.  It should last weeks but best used in one week.

There is also suction pumps and nitrogen.

Temperature for drinking is personal taste.

Comment: Just wondering why aluminum, is there a particular reason, would glass work?

Comment: Glass would work.  You just don't find many glass bottles with lids that seal.